# Access the user id in controller file not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes

On click the link edit i've passed the user's id

```
<span class="label label-success"><a href="{{ ('Edit') .$user->id}}">Edit</a></span>
```

The route file is

```
Route::get('Edit/{id}', ['uses' => 'PassengerController@edit', 'as'
=> 'edit']);
```

Now the url shows the user's id but i can't access the id in my controller

```
 public function edit($id)
 {

         echo $id;    
          // return view('home');
 }
```

When I run my project 
It shows **the page not found error**.

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking at `public function index($id)` instead of `public function edit($id)`?

Comment: I've updated my code now

Comment: Are you able to come in your function ? I mean do dd("here"); in your edit function and check whether it prints "here" or not.

Comment: It's not printing the statement

Comment: try this -    {{ url('edit/'). $user->id}}

Answer (score 0):

In the herf tag add `url` method name :

```
<span class="label label-success"><a href="{!! route('edit', ['id' => $user->id]) !!}">Edit</a></span>
```

And in the routes

```
Route::get('Edit/{id}', ['uses' => 'PassengerController@edit', 'as'
=> 'edit']);
```

Comment: @saranya you can accept the answer then :) like this => [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using route names, you can simply do `route('edit', [$user])` to get the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using resource route covention. I would suggest you use the following pattern:

```
Route::resource('passenger', 'PassengerController');
```

Then your link tag is updated as:

```
<span class="label label-success"><a href="{{ route('passenger.edit', $user) }}">Edit</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your href is wrong:

```
<span class="label label-success"><a href="{{ ('Edit') .$user->id}}">Edit</a></span>
```

should be

```
<span class="label label-success"><a href="/Edit/{{ $user->id }}">Edit</a></span>
```